# Nested table row in Material Design in Angular 6

Tags: angular, datatable, material-design, angular-material, angular6

I am trying to design Financial Expenditure Report of last 3 years in nested table using matrial-design. I want the output should look like [image]
I have nested json in which each parent can have `n` number of child. For instance

```
detailOfExpenditureSection= [
{
    sections: 'Revenue',
    headDetail: [{
        majorHeadNumber: '2403',
        majorHeadDescription: 'Animal Husbandry',
        subMajorHeadDetail: [{
            subMajorHeadNumber: '00',
            subMajorHeadDescription: '',
            minorHeadDetail: [{
                minorHeadNumber: '001',
                minorHeadDescription: 'Direction and Administration',
                subMinorHeadDetail: [{
                    subMinorHeadNumber: '60',
                    subMinorHeadDescription: 'Administration',
                    detailedHeadDetail: [{
                        detailedHeadNumber: '44',
                        detailedHeadDescription: 'Head Office Establishment',
                        objectHeadDetails: [{ objectHeadNumber: '01', objectHeadDescription: 'Salaries', actuals: '7327', budgetEstimate: '25664', revisedEstimate: '256891', budgetEstimateCurrentYear: '256914' },
                        { objectHeadNumber: '11', objectHeadDescription: 'Travel Expenses', actuals: '7327', budgetEstimate: '25664', revisedEstimate: '256891', budgetEstimateCurrentYear: '256914' },
                        { objectHeadNumber: '13', objectHeadDescription: 'Office Expenses', actuals: '7327', budgetEstimate: '25664', revisedEstimate: '256891', budgetEstimateCurrentYear: '256914' },
                        { objectHeadNumber: '26', objectHeadDescription: 'Advertisement and Publisity', actuals: '7327', budgetEstimate: '25664', revisedEstimate: '256891', budgetEstimateCurrentYear: '256914' },
                        ]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Where `sections` and its respective heads can be repeated. Considering this I am trying to design Table using material-table but unable to design the desired output.My problem is I am not been able to map actual and other right columns to the object head in the Head Deails Column. Because of that the row is mismatched. I have tried to map the column and row by creating directive by taking reference from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936762/angular-material-table-with-subrows-nested-cells-of-different-heights) but not been able to do so. How can get the desired output.

Comment: What does it look like with this code?

Comment: column and row are not sync with each other. Meaning object head is having value of actuals and so on but the values are coming not in sequence with the object head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table's source of data, which can be provided in three ways (in order of complexity):

1. Simple data array (each object represents one table row)
2. Stream that emits a data array each time the array changes
3. DataSource object that implements the connect/disconnect interface.

If a data array is provided, the table must be notified when the array's objects are added, removed, or moved. This can be done by calling the
    renderRows() function which will render the diff since the last
    table render. If the data array reference is changed, the table will
    automatically trigger an update to the rows.

When providing an Observable stream, the table will trigger an update automatically when the stream emits a new array of data.

Finally, when providing a DataSource object, the table will use the Observable stream provided by the connect function and trigger updates when that stream emits new data array values. During the table's ngOnDestroy or when the data source is removed from the table, the table will call the DataSource's disconnect function (may be useful for cleaning up any subscriptions registered during the connect process). The complete reference found [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api)

Change the json into flat structure and manipulate the data in the `.ts` file which works for me using `ngIf="SomeFunction()"` in the `.html` file.